# If then statement in R will not work

Tags: r

I am wondering why my if then the statement will not work.

---

```
if (gold_elements2$unit = "pct") 
  {gold_elements2$value * 10000}
```

[image: a picture of the top of my data set]

I want to multiply the values in the value column by 10000 that corresponds to the factor element `pct` in the unit column.

I keep getting the whole value column multiplied by 10000.
What is wrong?

Comment: Because '=' and '==' are different things.

Comment: Wrong placement of the `{` confuses the REPL when you feed it line by line. That is a FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made some data (in future please add actual sample data not screenshot of your data, its easier for people to replicate)

```
gold_elements2 <- data.frame(cbind(unit=c("pct","pcg","had","pct"), value=c(1,2,3,6)))
```

if you just want to extract the values at unit=pct and multiply by 1000 then this will work

```
as.numeric(gold_elements2[which(gold_elements2$unit=="pct"),"value"])*10000
```

output :

```
[1] 10000 40000
```

if you want to change the data in the the value column to be multipled by 1000 when  unit is pct then this will work

```
library(data.table)
gold_elements2 <- data.table(gold_elements2)
gold_elements2[,value:=ifelse(unit=="pct",as.numeric(value)*1000,value)]
gold_elements2
```

output :

```
   unit value
1:  pct  1000
2:  pcg     2
3:  had     3
4:  pct  4000
```